# Nservicebus - Worker Node not able to create dynamic queues

Tags: nservicebus3

We had a previous configuration stating Nservicebus not to create queues.
We removed that configuration from fluent to allow to create queues.

With the dynamic queue creation which is unique to each worker node, it is not creating queues for the worker node.

It throws the following error,

System.InvalidOperationException: There is a problem with the input queue: FormatName:DIRECT=OS:machinename\private$\nodename.2b75b263-4511-43d8-83b9-e1de5710fcdb. See the e
nclosed exception for details. ---> System.Messaging.MessageQueueException: The queue does not exist or you do not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation.
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.MQCacheableInfo.get_Transactional()
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.get_Transactional()
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.Msmq.MsmqMessageReceiver.QueueIsTransactional() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\nsb.master_2\src\impl\unicast\queuing\NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.Msmq\MsmqMess
ageReceiver.cs:line 124
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.Msmq.MsmqMessageReceiver.QueueIsTransactional() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\nsb.master_2\src\impl\unicast\queuing\NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.Msmq\MsmqMess
ageReceiver.cs:line 130
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.Msmq.MsmqMessageReceiver.Init(Address address, Boolean transactional) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\nsb.master_2\src\impl\unicast\queuing\NServiceBus.Unicast
.Queuing.Msmq\MsmqMessageReceiver.cs:line 34
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Transactional.TransactionalTransport.NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.ITransport.Start(Address address) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\nsb.master_2\src\impl\un
icast\transport\NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Transactional\TransactionalTransport.cs:line 180
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.NServiceBus.IStartableBus.Start(Action startupAction) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\nsb.master_2\src\unicast\NServiceBus.Unicast\UnicastBus.cs:line 828